# unix shell, getting exit code with piped child

Tags: unix, shell, io-redirection, exitstatus

Let's say I do this in a unix shell

```
$ some-script.sh | grep mytext

$ echo $?
```

this will give me the exit code of `grep`

but how can I get the exit code of `some-script.sh`

**EDIT**

Assume that the pipe operation is immutable. ie, I can not break it apart and run the two commands seperately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple solutions, it depends on what you want to do exactly.

The easiest and understandable way would be to send the output to a file, then grep for it after saving the exit code:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
./some-script.sh > $tmpfile
retval=$?
grep mytext $tmpfile
rm tmpfile
```

Comment: I see. Maybe that's a solution: `tmpfile=$(mktemp); (./some-script.sh; echo $? > $tmpfile) | grep mytext; retval=$(cat $tmpfile)`. That's quite dirty, but maybe it helps.

Comment: then grep gets the output of `echo $? > tmpfile`

Comment: No, because `echo $? > $tmpfile` has no output. The standard output of `echo` is sent to `$tmpfile`.

Comment: right, and that nothing gets passed to grep, it doesn't append the output of the first command

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood that correctly. The output of the first command (`./some-script.sh`) still reaches grep. Have you tried it? Maybe you could add the actual script with the problem and why the pipe operation is immutable.

Answer (score 4):

A trick from the [comp.unix.shell FAQ](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.unix.shell/msg/4db9f55afb677d36?dmode=source) (#13) explains how using the pipeline in the Bourne shell should help accomplish what you want:

> ```
>    You need to use a trick to pass the exit codes to the main
>    shell.  You can do it using a pipe(2). Instead of running
>    "cmd1", you run "cmd1; echo $?" and make sure $? makes it way
>    to the shell.
>
>    exec 3>&1
>    eval `
>      # now, inside the `...`, fd4 goes to the pipe
>      # whose other end is read and passed to eval;
>      # fd1 is the normal standard output preserved
>      # the line before with exec 3>&1
>      exec 4>&1 >&3 3>&- 
>      {
>        cmd1 4>&-; echo "ec1=$?;" >&4
>      } | {
>        cmd2 4>&-; echo "ec2=$?;" >&4
>      } | cmd3
>      echo "ec3=$?;" >&4
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bash:

```
PIPESTATUS
    An array variable (see Arrays) containing a list of exit status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).
```

Comment: I'm using sh. My client doesn't like bash

Answer (score 2):

There is a utility named `mispipe` which is part of the [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package.

It does exactly that: `mispipe some-script.sh 'grep mytext'`

Answer (score 0):

First approach, temporarly save exit status in some file. This cause you must create subshell using braces:

```
(your_script.sh.pl.others; echo $? >/tmp/myerr)|\ #subshell with exitcode saving
grep sh #next piped commands
exitcode=$(cat /tmp/myerr) #restore saved exitcode
echo $exitcode  #and print them
```

another approach presented by Randy above, simplier code implementation:

```
some-script.sh | grep mytext
echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} #print exitcode for first commands. tables are indexted from 0
```

its all. both works under bash (i know, bashizm). good luck :)
both approaches does not save temporarly pipe to physical file, only exit code.