# BASH scripting : Command result and pipeline

Tags: bash, unix, shell, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unix shell, getting exit code with piped child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851622/unix-shell-getting-exit-code-with-piped-child)

is it possible to have the result of a command (what's usually in $? variable) which is at the beginning of a pipeline ?

eg :

```
rm -rf filename_to_delete | tee -a log_filename
```

$? would contain the exit value of the tee statement, how can I have the exit value of the rm statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do I get the exit code of cmd1 in cmd1|cmd2](http://cfaj.ca/shell/cus-faq-2.html)